# Using convolution to derive first passage probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, laplace-transform, convolution

I'm reading through Sidney Redner's lectures on first passage processes (lectures [at this link](https://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/boulder-lectures-sr_03.pdf)) and I've been stuck on the convolution steps he takes to go from equation (3.1) to (3.2). He starts by relating the first passage probability $F(\textbf{r}, t)$ to the occupation probability $P(\textbf{r}, t)$ by the following equation:
$$
P(\textbf{r}, t) = \int_{0}^{t}{F(\textbf{r}, t')P(\textbf{0}, t-t')dt'} + \delta_{\textbf{r}, \textbf{o}}\delta_{t, 0}\text{.}
$$

I Laplace transform $P(\textbf{r}, t)$ as he suggests, but I end up with
$$
P(\textbf{r}, s) = \int_{0}^{s}{F(\textbf{r}, u)P(\textbf{0}, s-u)du} + \delta_{\textbf{r}, \textbf{0}}
$$

instead of $P(\textbf{r}, s) = F(\textbf{r}, s)P(\textbf{0}, s) + \delta_{\textbf{r}, \textbf{0}}$. I got to this point by substituting $P(\textbf{r}, t)$ into the Laplace transform, splitting the integral into two terms, then having the term without the delta functions look like
$$
P(\textbf{r}, s) = \int_{t=0}^{t=\infty}{\int_{t'=0}^{t'=t}{F(\textbf{r}, t)P(\textbf{0}, t-t')e^{-st}{dt}'}{dt}}\text{,}
$$

where the $t'$ integral is a convolution, so the outer integral is the Laplace transform of the convolution of $F(\textbf{r}, t)$ and $P(\textbf{0}, t)$:
$$
P(\textbf{r}, t) = \int_{t=0}^{t=\infty}{e^{-st}(F(\textbf{r}, t)*P(\textbf{0}, t))dt}=F(\textbf{r}, s) * P(\textbf{0}, s)\text{.}
$$

I'm not sure if I've made a mistake somewhere or if there's a connection between my final expression and Redner's - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a typo in your first expression. Looks like it should be a $F(r, t')$ not $F(r, t)$.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Thank you for noticing that!